# Owncloud - where in the SQL database is the email stored?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, owncloud

I am searching and searching but still cannot find it. In what table does owncloud store the email addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, it was in `oc_preferences`